# Dynamically set the onclick function in LWC button

Tags: lightning-web-components, dom, lightning-button, lwc-dom

I'm trying to dynamically set the onclick function of lightning web component button but it's not working. I've tried both "click" and "onclick"

JS:

```
const navButton = this.template.querySelector('.nav-button');
navButton.label = "Done";
navButton.addEventListener('onclick',this.handleShowMenu);
```

HTML:

```
<lightning-button 
   class="slds-m-left_small nav-button"
   label="Next"
   variant="brand"
   onclick={handleNext}>
</lightning-button>
```

Comment: Hi. Can you explain why you want to dynamically set it? You are already setting it using the onclick property binding in your template...

Comment: So I have a form so when the user gets to the last page I change the button label to "Done" and the onclick needs to change from "handleNext" to "handleFinished"

Comment: just one remark to your code sample: if you will use addEventListener() the corresponding string would be 'click' not 'onclick'

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to manually apply `onclick` event listener to `<lightning-button>`. But you can [handle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.events_handling) this or any other event in the container component. Just define the function `handleNext`:

```html
<!--container.html-->
<template>
   <lightning-button class="slds-m-left_small nav-button"
                     label="Next"
                     variant="brand"
                     onclick={handleNext}>
   </lightning-button>
</template>
```

```js
/* container.js */
export default class Container extends LightningElement {

   handleNext(event) {
       // handle onclick event
   }

}
```

Comment: I have a form so when the user gets to the last page I change the button label to "Done" and the onclick needs to change from "handleNext" to "handleFinished"

Comment: You can design any logic just within the `onclick` handler, keeping and manipulating the state in properties.

Comment: Yeah, I was planning to do that. Thanks for the help!